# Designing modern Desktop GUI

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, qtstylesheets

I want to develop a desktop program, and one of the most important criteria is having a wonderful user interface - both in terms of usability and style. When I say style, I mean the cool designs (and effects) that one normally associates with Android/Apple applications. I wish to design a user interface, similar (or inspired from) to the one designed for Light Table by Chris Granger. Here's the link to Light Table: http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ibdknox/light-table
Even Autodesk Maya has been designed using Qt.

Also, I wish to design the interface by drag-n-drop methods, so I finish the interface part quickly and move on to other important parts of the program. 
I've worked with Java Swing and AWT. But they provide native interfaces, which are good and easy to use, but doesn't fit the style/cool factor. So I tried Qt. Qt is a major improvement over Swing, I felt. But being new to it, I haven't been able to judge it's full capability. Interfaces of VLC and Maya have been designed with Qt, so I know Qt is the way to go. 
Now, Qt provides two major tools for UI design - Qt Designer and Qt Quick. 
Their docs and site say that Qt Designer should be used for Desktop applications and that it would give you a native style interface. But I don't want a native style interface. Qt Quick on the other hand, promises to give me exactly what I want (stylish looks etc), but their doc says Qt Quick is to be used for Mobile Application.

**Is it possible to use Qt Quick for desktop UI design?**

**Or, is it possible to extract out of Qt Designer, the kind of design I wish to implement?**

I also liked the Autodesk Maya interface design and would like to give my program that kind of touch. 
Besides, are there other or better cross-platform tools for UI design. Another reason for me choosing Qt is it is cross-platform. I want my program to run on Linux/Windows/Mac all the same.

Comment: Well, the question is slightly open-ended (and perhaps not appropriate in its current form), but the short answer is "Yes, you can achieve what you want with Qt". It will require some styling and customization, but with some effort it should certainly be possible.

Comment: Instead of trying to do "cool" UI, concentrate on making it usable and clear. There's enough software that's designed for stupid eye candy and at the same time practically unusable.

Comment: Yes, usability is the number 1 criterion. Won't compromise usability for making a cool UI. But it's good to have UI that's easy to use and also pleasing to the eye.

Comment: Take a look at Qt Quick Components for desktop if you're considering going that route. It's not finished, but there's clearly potential there. http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/03/10/qml-components-for-desktop/